# Interpretation of Yazid bin Harun

Tags: hadith, tafseer, hadith-interpretation

Where did Yazid bin Harun get such an opinion about the meaning of the word "al-ama" in the famous hadith (below)? Such a meaning is not given in dictionaries:

> The  governed noun `amā'  is derived from the Arabic root   amiya  the basic sense of which is` to become blind, to be obscure'. `Amā' could thus be translated "blindness", "secrecy", "obscurity" (etc.) though it also has the sense of` cloud', possibly  `heavy and thick clouds
> (which hide and obscure) or (the opposite!) light diaphanous clouds.

I do not think that Yazid himself invented it.

> (1)  The Sunan of  Muhammad ibn `Isā' Tirmidhi, "Abu Razin told that he asked God's messenger,` Where was our Lord before He created the creation?" to which he replied, " He was in obscurity (`ama') with no air below Him and no air above Him, and He created His Throne on the Water'"  (Sunan 4:351) (trans., J. Robson in Mishkat al-Masabih.. Vol. II (Lahore, 1975), pp. 1227 8

It is here noted that Tirmidhi transmitted this tradition and that Yazid ibn Hārūn al Wāsitiī(d. 206) said that "`amā' means that there was nothing with Him [God]").

https://hurqalya.ucmerced.edu/node/428

Such meanings of the word "Amā" as "nothing or emptiness or absence" are not found in dictionaries. Only as an interpretation of later scholars. Did Yazid ibn Harun mean the same thing, or did he have his own unique interpretation?

I edited my post, but there are still no replies.

Maybe my question has been forgotten, so I remind you of it.

Comment: Could you add the reference where Yazid bin Harun says that *""al-'Ama means that there was nothing on a par with (Allah)"."*

Comment: Ok.   https://hurqalya.ucmerced.edu/node/428

Comment: I couldn't find that al-'Ama means that there was nothing on a par with (Allah), rather al-ama means " the mist" in the linked site or" the blind"  according to Google Translate.

Comment: In that article that I threw off, there are these words of Yazid:

" It is here noted that Tirmidhi transmitted this tradition and that Yazid ibn Hārūn al Wāsitiī(d. 206) said that "`amā' means that there was nothing with Him [God]") ".

Comment: Please edit your post and quote the full statement and source you refer to , the context and details about the statement. Comments are not meant to last forever!

Comment: I have edited my post.

Comment: I edited my post, but there are still no replies.
Maybe my question has been forgotten, so I remind you of it.

Comment: Just because nobody answered doesn't necessarily mean it is forgotten... Some questions need research...

Comment: Got it, I'll be waiting.

Comment: My comment doesn't intend to stop you editing and improving your post from time to time, but please avoid changing it to a totally different question. So far my research comes to the conclusion that it is his own ijthad and interpretation, but I still check for more information.

Comment: Ok. I thought that if this word does not have such a meaning in the language itself, then maybe Yazid ibn Harun received such an interpretation along the chain from the Prophet.
Because I doubt very much that he came up with his own interpretation without any reason.
His biography does not say that he was engaged in kalam.

Comment: Are you still researching this issue?

Comment: If I have time ...

Comment: never received an answer.

Comment: How did Yazid come to this conclusion?